# C++ / Opencv Understanding the datatype being used

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I am wanting to learn OpenCV and using it for a licence plate detecting system in one of my projects. I have been following the steps outlined:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Cpp

The issue is that there is a class: `PossibleChar.h` which I cannot seem to get my head around what datatype this is using. I don't want to use a class within my algorithm as this does not follow the guidelines, however, the algorithm for that detecting number plates within the scene is what I need to do. The class looks like:

```
// PossibleChar.h

#ifndef POSSIBLE_CHAR_H
#define POSSIBLE_CHAR_H

#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

class PossibleChar {
public:
    // member variables
    std::vector<cv::Point> contour;

    cv::Rect boundingRect;

    int intCenterX;
    int intCenterY;

    double dblDiagonalSize;
    double dblAspectRatio;

    static bool sortCharsLeftToRight(const PossibleChar &pcLeft, const PossibleChar & pcRight) {
        return(pcLeft.intCenterX < pcRight.intCenterX);
    }


    bool operator == (const PossibleChar& otherPossibleChar) const {
        if (this->contour == otherPossibleChar.contour) return true;
        else return false;
    }


    bool operator != (const PossibleChar& otherPossibleChar) const {
        if (this->contour != otherPossibleChar.contour) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    // function prototypes
    PossibleChar(std::vector<cv::Point> _contour);

};

#endif  // POSSIBLE_CHAR_H
```

`PossibleChar.cpp`

```
PossibleChar::PossibleChar(std::vector<cv::Point> _contour) {
    contour = _contour;

    boundingRect = cv::boundingRect(contour);

    intCenterX = (boundingRect.x + boundingRect.x + boundingRect.width) / 2;
    intCenterY = (boundingRect.y + boundingRect.y + boundingRect.height) / 2;

    dblDiagonalSize = sqrt(pow(boundingRect.width, 2) + pow(boundingRect.height, 2));

    dblAspectRatio = (float)boundingRect.width / (float)boundingRect.height;
}
```

My initial thought was that all this class is doing is giving me `cv::Point`, which worked well until I moved onto calculating the distancing between 'Characters' on the number plate. This is the function given in the algorithm:

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const PossibleChar &firstChar, const PossibleChar &secondChar) {
    int intX = abs(firstChar.intCenterX - secondChar.intCenterX);
    int intY = abs(firstChar.intCenterY - secondChar.intCenterY);

    return(sqrt(pow(intX, 2) + pow(intY, 2)));
}
```

If I use one without using `PossibleChar`:

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const cv::Point &firstChar, const cv::Point &secondChar) {

  cv::Rect boundingRect;

  boundingRect = cv::boundingRect(firstChar);

}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'const cv::Point' (aka 'const Point_<int>') to 'const cv::_InputArray'
```

Which therefore leads me to believe that this class is not just returning a `cv::point` but also doing something else. Any ideas of how I could possibly get around this and calculate the distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PossibleChar` is not a `cv::Point`. It's a class containing the information for a *possible character*, let'a call it *blob*:

- `std::vector<cv::Point> contour;` the contour of the blob
- `cv::Rect boundingRect;` the bounding box (axis aligned) of the blob
- `int intCenterX; int intCenterY;`the coordinates of the center of the `bounding box`
- `double dblDiagonalSize; double dblAspectRatio;` size and aspect ratio of the `bounding box`

As you can see, it's not a `Point`, but contains the information about the *shape* and the *extent* of a given blob, which may be a *character*.

The function:

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const PossibleChar &firstChar, const PossibleChar &secondChar)
```

gives the euclidean distance between the centers of the two possible characters.
If you want to work with `cv::Point`, you can do:

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const cv::Point &firstChar, const cv::Point &secondChar) {
  return cv::norm(firstChar - secondChar);
}
```

which returns the euclidean distance between the two points, as before.

---

If you want to describe a `PossibleChar` as a `cv::Point` (which may be useful to you in your pipeline), you can consider the coordinates of the center:

```
cv::Point getPointFromPossibleChar(const PossibleChar& pc) {
    return cv::Point(pc.intCenterX, pc.intCenterY);
}
```

Comment: So in general terms, would it be better to use a class instead of trying to do it another way? I get it contains vital information, but I don't want this to come up further into the algorithm and find I need this information somehow - If this makes sense?

Comment: No,  not much sense ;). If you need this class, use this class. If you don't need it, don't use it. If you need to get a `cv::Point` that describes a `PossibleChar`, you can do as in my edit

Comment: Thanks for this. However, when looking through some of the code, it uses: `boundingRect` to get the area, width and height .. Is this still possible without using this class? They seem be converting it to a Bounding Rect to get these values

Comment: it uses  that to get the area because `PossibleChar` keeps this information.  If you just have a single point, you don't have any information about the area. I seriously don't get why you don't want to use this class....

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the way they calculated the distance between the two characters is suboptimal.

Though I think you shouldn't mix `cv::Point` with `PossibleChar`. They are different things and `PossibleChar` has a lot more information. Being that part of it is a `cv::Point` that describes the centre of mass of said `PossibleChar`.

If you have two `cv:Point` you can calculate the distance by:

`cv::Point a(1, 3);
cv::Point b(5, 6);
double res = cv::norm(a-b);//Euclidian distance`

---

If you decide to use the class, and I think you should just change

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const PossibleChar &firstChar, const PossibleChar &secondChar) {
    int intX = abs(firstChar.intCenterX - secondChar.intCenterX);
    int intY = abs(firstChar.intCenterY - secondChar.intCenterY);

    return(sqrt(pow(intX, 2) + pow(intY, 2)));
}
```

to

```
double distanceBetweenChars(const PossibleChar &firstChar, const PossibleChar &secondChar) {

        cv::Point a(firstChar.intCenterX,firstChar.intCenterY);
        cv::Point b(secondChar.intCenterX,secondChar.intCenterY);
        return(cv::norm(a-b));
}
```